# How do I remove or change the value of the software being run on my server (server header)?

Tags: apache, security, server, http-headers

OS:Mac

Server Software: Apache

Hosting: Shared

CMS: Wordpress

Using https://securityheaders.com/ to scan a client site for Security Headers, my results (under additional information) state:

"Server-  This Server header seems to advertise the software being run on the server but you can remove or change this value."

I've been able to remove the server signature and am comfortable editing the .htaccess to make changes, but my goal is to remove the server software from view (which I've unsuccessfully been able to find code for).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Capsule, thanks for the constructive criticism (& link) and for not down voting me. Although, I am unable to debug without a code to start with in the first place. Which makes me think, "Am I asking this question in the wrong place?" If so, do you recommend a different platform I should take this?

Answer (score -1):

First things first, The security signature is a default *"entity"* present in the header. Whenever someone hits up an error page (or a query that doesn't return some stuff..), if the headers aren't configured properly, the result throws out the server ver info along with the error 
For example a 404 not found error on a webpage will by default include a server version. So let's begin the security part...

1. Disable the apache server signature

Open the Apache config file, in your terminal paste the following command

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

And add the following line in the config file.

> ServerSignature Off

But even after disabling this signature, the traces of server version remain in the header response, to eliminate that, add the following line in the config file

> ServerTokens Prod

After that hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close it.
Next restart the service using this command

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

> If you are using a localhost server using xampp, use the GUI to restart it!

2. Hide the PHP(hypertext preprocessor) version

Open the PHP config file in your terminal using the following command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php.ini.default
```

Now add the following line in the file

> expose_php = Off

After that hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close it.
Now just restart the apache server to reload the PHP config!

Hope it helps, have a great day!

Comment: I don't have access to the apache config file due to shared hosting, but I do have access to the ".htaccess" file. I've also got the "expose_php" already turned off by editing the php.ini file itself.

Comment: Your answer doesn't respond to the OP question. Using `ServerTokens Prod` has no effect in removing server header.